# problem with cline in multirow, colored tabular

Tags: latex

I have a problem with using `\cline` and `\multirow` in a tabular, but the `clines` become hidden when I used to color in the table. Please help me to fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 
\newcommand{\key}{\rotatebox{90}}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule width 1.5pt}  >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}
        p{0.2cm} | p{7.5cm}}  \cline{1-1} 
    
    \multirow{5}{*}{\centering\key {AAAAAAAA}}   & \vspace*{-0.2cm}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
    \end{itemize} \\ \cline{1-1}  
    \multirow{21}{*}{\key{BBBBBBB}}   &  \vspace*{-0.2cm}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item  Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.  
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
    \end{itemize} \\ \cline{1-1}
    
    
    \multirow{6}{*}{\key{CCC}} & \vspace*{-0.2cm}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
    \end{itemize} \\ \cline{1-1}
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[the hidden clines show with blue circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl2Gi.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between `colortbl` and `cline`.

[The **colortbl** package*](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf)

> 10 Less fun with \cline
>
> Lines produced by \cline are coloured if you use \arrayrulecolor but you may not notice as they are covered up by any colour pannels in the following row. This is a ‘feature’ of \cline. If using this package you would probably better using the - rule type in a \hhline argument, rather than \cline.

---

I added the `hhline` package and adjusted the some values and did a little bit of formatting. [Note that under some conditions the line produced by `hhline` may seem to disappear, This is a problem with displaying a thin line, use a higher magnification.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcommand{\key}{\rotatebox{90}}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule width 1.5pt}
    >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}} p{0.2cm} | p{7.5cm}}  \hhline{-} 

    \multirow{6}{*}{\key{AAAAAAAA}}   &
    \vspace*{-0.2cm}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
    \end{itemize} \\ \hhline{-}  

    \multirow{14}{*}{\key{BBBBBBB}}   &
    \vspace*{-0.2cm}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.  
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
    \end{itemize} \\ \hhline{-}

    \multirow{4}{*}{\key{CCC}} &
    \vspace*{-0.2cm}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
        \item Mendeley Data Repository is free-to-use and open access.
    \end{itemize} \\ \hhline{-}
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

[image: Displayed Latex image]